# Eclipse could not write to ./launch

Tags: java, eclipse, remote-debugging

I have accidentally deleted ./metadata folder in eclipse. Now when i try reconfigure the project from workspace, things are fine and the project gets created with some old data about libraries. But when i try to create a new remote java application for debugging, i get the following error

```
"Could not write file:/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches"
```

Can someone please tell me how do i rectify this error and start remote java debugging?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling eclipse?

Comment: Reinstalling eclipse!:( is there any other alternative way to sort this out?

Comment: What does the Eclipse log show (in the  .metadata/.log file)? Is there a related stack trace? Have you tried starting Eclipse with the `-clean` command line option, in case it helps?

Comment: Restore ./metadata from backup?

Comment: Windows - undelete ./metadata from recycle bin?

Comment: @DavidPostill No am using a linux machine so no way to retrieve it i guess!:'(

Comment: Reinstalling Eclipse probably won't help as that won't touch the workspace metadata. It is probably best to create a new workspace and import the projects from the old one.

Comment: @Lolo fortunately the launch using -clean has worked!!! thanks:)

Answer (score 7):

Create the missing directory in the workspace

cd /workspace/.metadata/.plugins 
mkdir org.eclipse.debug.core 
chmod -R 777 org.eclipse.debug.core

Answer (score 0):

**You need create the missing directory.**
If you use windows, you can create a new directory using windows explorer or you can use the following command line *for windows and linux:*

```
cd /workspace/.metadata/.pluguins
mkdir org.clipse.debug.core
```

OBS: You don't need to use 'chmod' command line.

Answer (score 0):

on MAC for example, you need to put to your IDE the authorisation to write on the disk. Privacy & Security/Full Disk Access. There you need to put your IDE (Eclipse, IntelliJ or Spring STS).